# Fable forecast data set requests and functions

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, fable-r

does any one have the dataset requirements for fable package in R
here some problems I had, any one can give any suggestion will be nice.
my R version is

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          5.2
year           2018
month          12
day            20
svn rev        75870
language       R
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo

1. could I use irregular time data for modeling?
   say: I have price data for 250 days out of 365 days but I still want to use fable to model ARIMA of the price. 
   is that possible? 
   the example form github is uesing tsibbledata::ausretail 
   has no  missing date in the data set
2. seems the commend the fable pacakge grammar changed
   I was using the example from this page 2018-12 it was fine
   https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/fable-tfeam-2018/blob/master/index.Rmd

but now I am not able to use the code. 
e.g. the ETS was using

```
fbl_cafe_fit <- vic_cafe %>%
  fable::ETS(Turnover ~ season("M"))
```

now from this page, people need to put extra 'model' outside??
https://github.com/tidyverts/fable

```
    UKLungDeaths %>%
  model(ets = ETS(log(mdeaths))) %>%
  forecast
```

is that new grammar or my understanding is wrong?

3. Seems now i do not have auto.arima () option from fable any more???
   i need to specify  pdq() and PDQ()

   USAccDeaths %>% as_tsibble %>% 
     model(arima = ARIMA(log(value) ~ pdq(0,1,1) + PDQ(0,1,1)))
4. after i fit the arima model, i also have problem use the fitting model to predict next period
   this grammar not work any more:

   fbl_cafe_fc <- fbl_cafe_fit %>% forecast(h=24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ARIMA requires a regular time series, however it will also work in the presence of missing values. You can use `tsibble::fill_gaps()` to convert implicit missing values to explicit.
2. Correct, the fable package is currently experimental and changes to the interface are expected to continue. These changes will likely have a relatively minor impact on users. Since the fable TFEAM talk, we now support multiple model columns in a mable. To achieve this, we now use `model()` to specify models. Previously, if you wanted to model `data %>% ETS(log(y) ~ season("A"))`, this is now `data %>% model(ETS(log(y) ~ season("A"))`.
3. Automatic model selection (such as `forecast::auto.arima()`) is contained within the same function in fable (`ARIMA()`). When estimating a model, if the right-hand-side is left empty, a model will be chosen automatically from the defaults. For ARIMA models, if you used `data %>% model(ARIMA(y))`, an appropriate model will be automatically chosen (same as `forecast::auto.arima()`). You can also now estimate an ARIMA(p,0,0)(2,1,Q)[12] model, where `p` and `Q` are unknown between 0 and 3. To do this, you would use `data %>% model(ARIMA(y ~ pdq(0:3, 0, 0) + PDQ(2, 1, 0:3, period = 12)))`.
4. That code looks correct, and should still work. Perhaps you need to update the packages.

Comment: One more question here,@Mitchell O'Hara-Wild,  if i want to use weekly data for prediction(I have tsibble showing it is [7d] ts already), if i want to use auto ARIMA model. should i use: `data %>% model(ARIMA(y))`, or should I use `data %>% model(ARIMA(y),period=52)`? Thank you!

Comment: If you have weekly data, I'd first suggest using the yearweek() class for your index. An annual seasonal pattern for your weekly data will be selected by default in ARIMA, however to make this more explicit you could use `data %>% model(ARIMA(y ~ PDQ(period = 52)))`. Note that you could also use `period = "year"`.